# Convert a Value in a Column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a Dataframe with a column called "Number"
The values in the column look like this:
1.2.1
2.3.1
2.4.1
Now I want to filter based on the value in this column. But I just to check the first Number: Thats means that 2.3.1 and 2.4.1 are the same for me (2)
So I just to filter like "Number" == 2
How do I convert them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df[df['Number'].str.startswith('2.')]
```